# Arduino driven servomotor stops working when sensor is attached

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to create somekind of eyes for my robot. It will use a servo for rotation **Ultrasonic Meter HC-SR04**, but when I add code to drive this thing, servo stops working. Why is so? I'm using Arduino 1.5.6 and **Arduino Uno R3.**

*Code:*

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 90;    // variable to store the servo position 
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int hcsr04[4] = {13,12,11,10};
float echoTime = 0;
float distance = 0;
void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(3);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.write(pos);
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    pinMode(hcsr04[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(hcsr04[1], INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{ 
  x = analogRead(A0);
  y = analogRead(A1);

  if(y < 100)
  {
    pos += 1;
    if(pos >= 175)
    {
      pos -= 10;
    }
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(10);
  }
  if(y > 900)
  {
    pos -= 1;
    if(pos <= 5)
    {
       pos += 10;
    }
    myservo.write(pos);
  delay(10);
  }
  digitalWrite(hcsr04[0], LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
   digitalWrite(hcsr04[0], HIGH );
  delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(hcsr04[0], LOW);
    echoTime = pulseIn(hcsr04[1], HIGH);
   distance = echoTime / 58;
    Serial.println(pos);
}
```

Comment: Try doing Serial.println(y) after your analog reads might turn up something. If y is between 100 and 900 it never hits any servo movement code. Both your if statements only detect values outside that range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pulseIn() function uses the same timer that Servo is using... You could use attachInterrupt() and substract time() - oldTime in callback, then assign time() to oldTime

Example: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt